# I'm unable to debug this code, not sure what logic i am missing

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

Given an array of integers arr of even length n and an integer k.
We want to divide the array into exactly n/2 pairs such that the sum of each pair is divisible by k.
Return True If you can find a way to do that or False otherwise.

e.g.

1. `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,10,6,7,8,9], k = 5, output: True`
2. `arr = [-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2,-2,-2], k = 3, output: False`

**The code i've written:**

```
def canArrange(self, arr: List[int], k: int) -> bool:
    dictt = {}
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] = arr[i] % k
        if arr[i] not in dictt:
            dictt[arr[i]] = 1
        else:
            dictt[arr[i]] += 1
    count = 0
    for num in arr:
        if (k-num) == num:
            if dictt[num] > 1:
                dictt[num] -= 2
                count += 1
            else:
                dictt[num] -= 1
        if (k-num) in dictt and dictt[(k-num)] != 0 and dictt[num] != 0:
            dictt[(k-num)] -= 1
            dictt[num] -= 1
            count += 1
        elif num == 0 and dictt[num] > 1:
            dictt[num] -= 2
            count += 1
    if count == len(arr)//2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

*My logic is I am first taking the count of "every element % k" and the finding its another pair and reducing the count of both to avoid duplicates, one special case is when the values in a pair are same so for that i am already decrementing the value in my dictionary and at last i am checking whether the number of pairs are equal to half of elements or not*
**I am able to pass 93/97 test cases on leetcode, and unable to debug for the rest as the length of these 4 test cases are huge hence not possible manually, i must be missing some points while setting my logic, kindly help**

**Edit: DONE (I have edited the code above)**

Comment: It would help to provide a test case that is not working - what's the input, the expect output and the actual output.

Comment: Why don't you trace out the case `arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], k = 2`? By inspection your algorithm returns `False` when it should return `True`.

Comment: Also, the `elif num == 0` special case seems weird: why is a zero element treated specially? If you write out fully what the logic should be for the second for loop (in words), you can check whether your code matches that logic.

Comment: This [1,1,1,1,1,1], k = 2 helped me debug it, thanks a lot!